Displaying results from one table following a join of three tables
I have 3 tables of data (scans, samples, sales). I am trying to identify clinic id's that are present in all three tables. Once that group is identified, I want to display results of that group from only the sales table. Because some of the clinic id's are present in multiple instances in the scans or samples tables, I am seeing results multiplied by the number of instances in the scans or samples tables.
For identifying clinic id's present in all three tables...
SELECT DISTINCT sales.clinic_id, sales.clinic FROM sales
JOIN samples ON sales.clinic_id = samples.clinic_id
JOIN scans ON samples.clinic_id = scans.clinic_id
WHERE sales.clinic_id !='';

For identifying how often clinic id's purchased and how many items they purchased...
SELECT DISTINCT sales.clinic_id, sales.clinic, COUNT(sales.clinic_id), SUM(sales.quantity) FROM sales
JOIN samples ON sales.clinic_id = samples.clinic_id
JOIN scans ON samples.clinic_id = scans.clinic_id
WHERE sales.clinic_id !=''
GROUP BY sales.clinic_id, sales.clinic;

Results from this query include multiplication factors that I am trying to eliminate. The data set is small enough right now such that I can verify results externally.

Without seeing your data, it appears you might not have proper data normalization.
If the "Clinic" is a descriptive name for a given "Clinic_ID".  Seeing sample data
would help confirm and possibly better structure help.  Does "Clinic" ALWAYS correspond to "Clinic_ID".  I would EDIT your post and show sample data from each table that is causing the multiplication factor.   Simple text and space alignment for readability.

Results from this query include multiplication factors that I am trying to eliminate. You'd count/sum your clinic data by the clinic table only in the subquery then join all other tables.

I appreciate you taking the time to provide assistance with my questions. Only a couple of months into my MySQL journey. For this particular issue, I was able to create a view with my query containing multiple joins. I was then able to join that view with my sales table and get the desired results. Looking forward to continued learning on this site. Thanks again.
